# including eps file in latex

Tags: graphics, eps

I have a problem in including eps figures in my paper. Thanks for your help. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{amssym}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\input{epsf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{fig10.eps}}
    \caption{Parallel system}\label{fparallelT}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. The code works for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As Philipp says, can you explain how it doesn't work, what happens? (Unrelated comments: Should `\input{amssym}` be `\usepackage{amssymb}`? Also, I doubt there would be any need for `epsf` when you have `graphicx`. And I think that using `\centering ...` is recommended over `\centerline{..}`.)

Comment: `epsf` is declared obsolete and replaced with \graphicx`  in `l2tabu`.

Comment: remove the `[demo]` option to graphicx, remve `input epsf` remove `\centerline`, use `\centering` then it should work

Comment: Actually, the demo option was not present in the OP. I added it in order to make his code a MWE.